# Code structure for client specific library / plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture

So here is the problem:

I have some logic in my application that will be different on a client by client basis. What is the best way to do structure this so that it can be configured without any code changes. I have already added an appsetting to the config like so:

```
<add key="MyCalculationType" value="MyApp.Client1.Calculation,MyApp.Client1" />
```

In my core business logic:

```
ICalculation abcCalculation = CalculationFactory.GetManager(); // Uses appsetting to get type

abcCalculation.Calculate(this);
```

I have added a new project called MyApp.Client1, which I want to contain the client specific implementation of Calculate.

```
namespace MyApp.Client1
{
    public class Calculation : ICalculation
    {
        public void Calculate(Order o)
        {
            // Calculate properties of order
        }
    }
}
```

I have not finished yet, so I can't provide any output. At this stage I want to know, before I go any further, whether there is a better way of acheiving what I am trying to. One thing I don't know for sure is where to put the ICalculation interface. I think the way I have it may give circular reference errors.

Many thanks

**EDIT**

As I suspected, the ICalculation interface is preventing me from building. Though not with a cyclic reference error; with a "Cannot resolve symbol" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ICalculation` interface can be inside your *ConnectorBridge* library, which manages access, subscribtion and communication of external plugins with host environment.

Your application and (say) Calculation project, both contain the reference to *ConnectorBridge*. In this way Calculation can implement an `ICalculation` interface and appliaction get access to abstraction.

Create a folder in your application, say *Plugins*  and on startup of your app you scan content of that folder for DLL's where is present type that implements `ICalculation` interface. ONe time the type is found (Calculator in this sepcific case) it's created, and preserved in application for future execution.

These are just a copuple of ideas, but *concrete* implementation, naturally, requires much more work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will try this and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do that sort of thing you should look to a proper [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container.  I prefer [NInject](http://www.ninject.org) since it is quite powerful and very configurable.

Comment: It is quite a large project. Will it be a lot of work to use NInject?

Comment: It can be, but it is straight forward enough. @Tigran has a good idea that goes well with dependency injection.